# Find inverse of cos

Tags: c#

at http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Trigonometry/solve_trig_SSS.htm
there is 
"Find the inverse cos of -0.25 using a scientific calculator...C = cos-1(-0.25)= 104.478º "
and
"Find the inverse sin of 0.484123 using a scientific calculator...A = sin-1(0.484123)= 28.955º "

I am trying to do this in c# , so i am trying the following

```
        double mycalc =   Math.Asin(0.484123)  ;
        double mycalc2 = Math.Acos(-0.25);
        double mycalc99 = Math.Pow(Math.Acos(-0.25), -1);  // or Math.Cos
        double mycalc66 =  Math.Pow(Math.Asin(0.484123), -1) ;  // or Math.Sin
```

What steps am I missing?
Should I use `DegreeToRadian` function?

Using  calculator  net  scientific-calculator.html

> 0.484123 asin does equal 28.955029723
>   -0.25 acos does equal 104.47751219

So what is missing?

Answer (score 23):

- `cos`<sup>-1</sup> means the inverse function of `cos`. It does **not** mean `cos` raised to the power `-1`. (similar thing with `sin`) ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions))
- `Asin` and `Acos` return the angle in **[Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radians)**, you have to convert it to **Degrees**.

You should use :

```
double mycalcInRadians = Math.Asin(0.484123);
double mycalcInDegrees = mycalcInRadians * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 10):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.asin.aspx), Asin and Acos definitely return in radians.

> Multiply the return value by `180/Math.PI` to convert from radians to
>   degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, After a sleep it became obvious.
I needed `RadianToDegree`.

```
private double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
{
    return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}

private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
{
    return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```